# JVM throws Exception

Tags: jvm, java, rhel

I am using RHEL 6.0 with JRE1.6.0_43 installed. It's installed properly and java plugin for browser also working fine. But I am facing the problem while running java_vm in /jre/bin directory.
While running for the first time it throws,

> java_vm process: You need to set both JAVA_HOME and PLUGIN_HOME

Then i set the JAVA_HOME=/ and PLUGIN_HOME=/plugin, after that it throws the following exception while running java_vm,

> java_vm process: Couldn't find class sun/plugin/navig/motif/Plugin
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   sun/plugin/navig/motif/Plugin Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.plugin.navig.motif.Plugin at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

Then i modified the PLUGIN_HOME=/ , when i try to run again it shows another exception,

> Java process: caught exception from
>   sun.plugin.navig.motif.Plugin.start Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   sun.plugin.navig.motif.Plugin.start(Unknown Source)

After this, I don't know what to do to get rid of this problem... I think the problem is with PLUGIN_HOME variable.. Please provide me the clear details about PLUGIN_HOME and tell me why we need this variable?

Comment: Why are you running java_vm and not java?

Comment: One of my application requires this.